# When to use async and await - client vs webapi

Tags: c#, azure, rest, asp.net-web-api

I'm building a planner using ASP.NET Web Api in which it currently does some simple CRUD operations. One of the main purposes of this API is to be able to accept requests from different platforms (web and android app client). My question is in regards to best practices for async and await and web api (as well as what makes sense) - where should I provide asynchrony? At the client level or at the API level (server)?

I know one of the main purposes of async and await is to provide responsiveness for the UI. And I know the asynchronous model mainly covers I/O bound or CPU bound operations. I'm guessing in this sense, my process would fall under I/O bound. But best practices wise, should the API be asynchronous or should that stay within the client? My api will be running on Azure's app service.

Below is an example "Get" action in my API (synchronous and not actual code):

```
[Authorize]
[Route("GetUser/{userId}")]
public IHttpActionResult GetUser(int userId)
{
    return Ok(/* method calls are done here... */);
}
```

My proposed asynchronous example:

```
[Authorize]
[Route("GetUser/{userId}")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetUser(int userId)
{
    return Ok(await /* method calls are done here... */);
}
```

And I'm using HttpClient to make requests to the api.

My expectation is that multiple persons will be using the client. So I would assume that the client should be asynchronous and the api can stay synchronous. But again, I'm trying to figure what's the best thing to do here (best practices wise).

Comment: Why do you assume that only one application can make use of asynchronous operations?  Treat each application individually.  If that application is performing asynchronous operations, do so asynchronously.

Comment: In the **server side**, going `async` will let you handle more requests (hence you achieve *scalability*). In the **client side**, using `async` will free-up the UI thread (assuming its the one that is issuing the request) while the OS is waiting for the bits to arrive (hence you achieve *responsiveness*)

Comment: So @haim770 you're essentially saying go asynchronous all the way?

Comment: @Jae, It depends on your needs. If you expect high load on your server and it's doing mostly IO, then `async` is a reasonable choice. Anyway, you have to realize that the fact that the client using async http, does not mean that the server has to be async as well. Your UI could still be responsive even if the server is blocking its own thread, and the thread-pool in your server can still re-use worker threads regardless of whether the client is async.

Comment: Cool, thanks @haim770, makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's a web server there's no thread responsible for updating the UI like in a local app.  So that's not really a consideration.

The main advantage of async/await in a web server is that when you await a long I/O operation, the thread is freed up to do other tasks.  If your web server is really being hammered, say 100 hits/sec and it's using every thread in its thread pool, then new web requests have to wait until a thread gets freed before they can be processed.

If you're not being hit that hard and/or you don't have relatively long I/O operations, your first code snippet is fine, you don't need to delve into the complexity of async/await.  On the client side, however, you should use async to do these web server calls since they are I/O calls and could block the UI thread.

Comment: Ah, ok, so essentially what you're saying is, on the api side, unless I'm experiencing high traffic, there is no need to go asynchronous. But on the client side its a definite (UI responsiveness and all).

Comment: Yeah.  @haim770 worded it well and succinctly in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

Since you've asked for the best practice, go async all the way.
Async only gets complex (and gets you in trouble) when you try to make it work it in a synchronous fashion. Go async all the way (very easy to do with asp.net core), and you'll be good.

Source: https://github.com/davidfowl/AspNetCoreDiagnosticScenarios/blob/master/AsyncGuidance.md

(If an API action isn't doing anything async in nature, you can leave async out on that API, but default to async.)

Comment: I guess this would make sense scabality wise. But what exactly do you mean by:

"If an API action isn't doing anything async in nature, you can leave async out on that API, but default to async."

Are you saying if the method is by nature synchronous then leave it as is?

Comment: @Jae yup. Basically make everything async by default, and leave it out if it's not needed. Not the other way around.

Comment: Thanks for the AsyncGuidance @gldraphael

Comment: @Jae all thanks to David Fowler and everyone else that contributed to it.